# how to find the complexity of T(n) = T(3n/4) + T(n/3) + n^2

Tags: math, time-complexity, recurrence

I was asked to find the asymptotic complexity of the given function using recursion tree
but I'm struggling to find the correct complexity at each level

Answer (score 0):

Let's draw out the first two levels of the recursion tree:

```
                +------------------+
                | Input size n     |
                | Work done: n^2   |
                +------------------+
                  /               \
   +--------------------+     +--------------------+
   | Input size: 3n/4   |     | Input size: n/3    |
   | Work done: 9n^2/16 |     | Work done: n^2/9   |
   +--------------------+     +--------------------+
```

Once we've done that, let's sum up the work done by each layer. That top layer does n<sup>2</sup> work. That next layer does

> (9/16)n<sup>2</sup> + (1/9)n<sup>2</sup> = (43/48)n<sup>2</sup>

total work. Notice that the work done by this second level is (43/48)ths of the work done in the level just above it. If you expand out a few more levels of the recursion tree, you'll find that the next level does (43/48)<sup>2</sup>n<sup>2</sup> work, the level below that does (43/48)<sup>3</sup>n<sup>2</sup> work, and that more generally the work done by level l in the tree is (43/48)<sup>l</sup>n<sup>2</sup>. (Convince yourself of this - don't just take my word for it!)

From there, you can compute the total amount of work done by recursion tree by summing up the work done per level across all the levels of the tree. As a hint, you're looking at the sum of a geometric sequence that decays from one term to the next - does this remind you of any of the cases of the Master Theorem?